# Need Simple Has_Many :through controller code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm learning to use Rails has_many :through association. Most of what I'm reading provides only how to set up the models, but not how to set up the controller actions. My app is very basic for the purposes of learning this topic. I have a form that lists some vertical industries. When a "vertical" is created, there is an option to select from a list of apps that apply to that vertical (check boxes). When the vertical gets created, the associations between the vertical and the selected apps should be established.

I have 3 models:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :solutions
  has_many :verticals, through: :solutions
end

class Vertical < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :solutions
  has_many :apps, through: :solutions
end

class Solution < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app
  belongs_to :vertical
end
```

Here is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@vertical) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.association :apps,   as: :check_boxes %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my verticals_controller create action:

```
  def create
    @vertical = Vertical.new(vertical_params)
    @solutions = @vertical.apps.build(params[:app])
    <respond_to code omitted for brevity>
  end

  def vertical_params
      params.require(:vertical).permit(:name, :description, apps_attributes: [ :name, :description, :developer, :mpp, :partner, :website, :app_id[] ])
  end
```

I am able to create the associations from the rails console this way:

```
vertical = Vertical.first
app = App.first
vertical.apps << app
```

But I don't think this is the right way to do it in the controller, nor do I understand how to get the app params that were selected in the form. I'm looking for some basic, clean code examples to follow that adhere to Rails best practices. Also, if you can point me to any recent tutorials that address controller code would be great. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the associations to be created by making the following changes:

In my Create action in my controller:

```
  def create
    @vertical = Vertical.new(vertical_params)
    @solutions = @vertical.apps.build
    <respond_to code omitted for brevity>
  end
```

In my secure parameters I have the following:

```
  def vertical_params
      params.require(:vertical).permit(:name, :description, app_ids:[])
  end
```

I am not certain this is done to Rails best practices or not.